# "Invalid read of size 1" with mysql_free_result

Tags: c, valgrind, libmysql

I'm trying to get a value from a database and store it in a global variable like so:

```
mysql_query(con, query);
MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);
if ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))    
{
    global_variable = row[1];  
}  
mysql_free_result(result);
```

But, I'm getting a "Invalid read of size 1" in Valgrind, whenever I try to access my global_variable.

```
==13345== Invalid read of size 1
...
==13345==  Address 0x60a3fea is 74 bytes inside a block of size 8,160 free'd
...
==13345==    by 0x4E67E9C: mysql_free_result (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just saving the pointer, not the actual data. The data is `free'd` by the call to `mysql_free_result`, your `global_variable` is then just a dangling pointer to unsafe memory.

You need to `memcpy` or `strncpy` the content of `row[1]` in your own buffer to use it later, or you could use it before calling `mysql_free_result`.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fetch-lengths.html for how you can retrieve row lengths to copy them.